# Monitoring traffic on a dummy interface

Tags: command-line, networking

I've created a dummy interface using Ifconfig:

```
ifconfig enp2s0:1 192.168.125.1/24
```

I want to monitor traffic on it. Meaning I want to measure how much data has gone through it in a specific time.

```
 cat /sys/class/net/enp2s0/statistics/rx_bytes
 cat /sys/class/net/enp2s0/statistics/tx_bytes
```

and tools like vnstat only work for the main interface. Is there anyway I could achieve this? If not, is there a tool I could use to measure the outgoing/incoming between two specific times on a subnet?

Comment: Check /proc/net/dev

Comment: Same way you would monitor traffic on any network device, there are many methods, your question is too broad.

Comment: its not the same way, ifconfig, ls /sys/class/net and netstat -i  don't show statistics for the the interface

Comment: also /proc/net/dev doesn't show the interface